# How to include in the filter http requests satisfying the given condition and the respective responses?

Tags: wireshark

For example, I want to see all the http requests containing the given string in the `http.host` field and their respective responses. Right now my filter is `frame.number < 61403 and http.host contains tdc1`. But it omits the responses and I have no idea how to add them.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The answer was not satisfying. And I have no way of knowing if there is a better answer without delving deep into it myself. Which I do not have the time now.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat practical method is to

1. select one of the packets in question
2. expand *Transmission Control Protocol*
3. look for the *[Stream index: `n`]* metatag
4. change or expand your filter to/with *tcp.stream eq `n`*

Alternatively, you can just right-click the packet and select *Follow → TCP Stream* or hit `Ctrl`-`Shift`-`Alt`-`T` - this overwrites your current filter though.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to filter on the requests and responses separately, then merge the pcap files.

Comment: Ouch. Is by "merging" you mean simple concat?

Comment: Wireshark can merge files.

Comment: How can I filter responses matching the filters? E.g. I can filter requests by the http.host field. But how can I get the respective responses?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What data are you looking for?

Comment: I have captured HTTP traffic outgoing from my build agent. Some traffic goes to the Azure DevOps Server, some goes to other machines - has to do with the fact that the build agent is in Azure. I want to concentrate only on the traffic to the Azure DevOps Server - inspect the requests and their corresponding responses. I may further reduce the amount of "interesting" requests and would like to see their matching responses.

Comment: Is the *follow tcp stream* command helpful here?

Comment: I do not understand how to use it. E.g. the filter `http.host contains tdc1` returns 609 requests. What I want is to see 609 corresponding responses along with their requests. All in all 1218 records - half requests, half responses. I do not see how follow tcp stream helps me there. At least I failed to figure it out.